# My for in loop output fork fails

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this "for in" tutorial and I don't understand why I can't get the loop to write the aProperty value instead of just its name.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bi...=javascript_15

I've tried:
document.write(navigator.aProperty);
document.write(navigator + . + aProperty);
And various other forms, all have failed.

If I just code
document.write(navigator.onLine); 
Why can't I make the var, "aProperty" work as a document.write parameter?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var aProperty;
document.write("Navigator Object Properties<br /> ");
for (aProperty in navigator)
 {
document.write(aProperty);
document.write("<br />");
}
document.write("Exiting from the loop!");

//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*aProperty* is, indeed, just the key. to return the value you need to ask *navigator* for it.

Add this in your for...in loop:

```
for (aProperty in navigator)
{
    document.write(navigator[aProperty]);
    document.write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: that's great, @Billy_Bob , please mark this question as answered :)